# How to test mongoid falsy saving attempt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

The goal is to test both case of the following control structure embedded in an controller update method:

```
  if @example.save
    flash[:success] = 'Fine'
    redirect_to some_path(@example.id)
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Failed!'
    redirect_to some_other_path(@example.id)
  end
```

The positive case is easy, it's enough to call `patch` with the update matching path, `save` will works returning `true`, and that's all. However having `Mongoid::Persistable#save` to return `false` is less obvious and I actually didn't found a way to do it so far.

Is it even possible without modifying the code that is tested?

Here is a fictional example of test I would find OK, but other solution would be welcome:

```
test 'save failure' do
    Mongoid.fail_on_save do
      post modify_example_path(@example) #
      assert_equal 'Failed!', flash[:error]
    end
end
```

A way to overload the Mongoid::Persistable::Savable#save method should do the trick, but I don't know how to successfully overload methods defined in modules.

Comment: `save` will return false if, say, validations are violated. So you could post invalid data.

Comment: You also always explicitly stub `save` method

Comment: @SergioTulentsev stubbing the save method for this test to return false sounds like a good way to test this.  But could also cause problems if done incorrectly.  can you make an answer showing how you would stub the save method to return false for this specific test?

Comment: Are you using rspec?

Comment: I'm not using rspec.

Comment: @psychoslave Then I can't help you :) Also, don't forget to `@mention` people.

Comment: In simple case, posting invalid data is fine. However I also want to test a duplication which doesn't use the whole passed `@example` values but instead retrieve most data from directly from database through a logic abstraction layer.

Comment: RE your last edit. You don't need to touch the module. If you were to stub/override, do it on `@example` directly. It is the example that handles the `save` message, not the module.

Comment: This may be not applicable to your case, but in ruby you can do this: `def @example.save; false; end`

Comment: Thank you @SergioTulentsev but guess indeed in won't work in my case, as the posted `@example` is not the instance of which `save` is used against. What I would need is at least override the matching class I guess.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev any suggestion on how I may overload `Mongoid::Persistable::Savable#save` or `@example.class#save`?

Comment: @psychoslave: in rspec you can do `expect_any_instance_of(Example).to receive(:save).and_return(false)`

Comment: Thank you @SergioTulentsev, I'll consider using rspec then.